# Promise failing with save() and get(), using Node Webkit, Sequelize, and SQLite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, node-webkit

I'm not exactly sure what my problem is, but the title is my best guess. Included are my error logs and thought process. I hope someone can help.

```
/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/captured_trace.js:478 Unhandled rejection Error: TypeError: Illegal invocation
          at Object.ensureErrorObject (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:228:20)
          at Promise._rejectCallback (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:416:22)
          at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:460:17)
          at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:530:18)
          at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:646:14)
          at Async._drainQueue (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:177:16)
          at Async._drainQueues (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:187:10)
          at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/fjcero/project/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
          at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:321:17)
```

I started using SQLite as a single application data store. I choose Sequelize as ORM since is pretty straightforward. In the web context, that means running the Application through Node.js everything works as expected. The issues began when I tried to run the same Application in the NW.js context.

First, SQLite3 should be compiled in a [particular way](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#building-for-node-webkit). I do it and everything goes well. I defined the Sequelize models and and when `sync()` is executed all the tables are created if not exists, and the schema is the specified. This means, at some point SQLite3 and Sequelize are connecting well, and everything goes as expected.

The weird issue begins when I try to use `save()` or `get()` methods, since something with Promises fails. I suppose that could be due the compilation of the SQLite module with support for NW. I don't know if it's the library fault, or some missing flag, or that NW context broke something between Sequelize and SQLite communication. Since this happens only in a NW context, I opted to ask here so I could learn what I'm doing wrong or how I could debug this thing.

Any start point will be appreciated, either is the solution, or it's explaining how to debug this inside Node Webkit.